# How I can create a graph of acceleration and speed - tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, diagrams

How can I create a graph of acceleration and speed like the one in the picture. Knowing that they are each other's consequence?

[image]

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

```
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}



           \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you have the equations?

Comment: @Alenanno  No, I don't because they are theoretical graphs

Comment: From the picture, If one is allowed to guess that the acceleration is a straight line, then the equations *do* exist viz a(t) = c - mt, v(t) = v(0) + ct - mt^2/2 etc. Just find by trial and error, good values for c and m so that the picture looks good. If the shape of acceleration is not a straight line, then one would have to do symbolic or numerical integration to make the pictures consistent.

Comment: @Ilmionome456 In that case, you can use simple curves and paths, although it might require some more trial and error.

Comment: -1: This exact question has been asked by you before; [Graphs of the motions - physical](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/298996/30280), and you have been on the site long enough to understand how this community works.

Comment: @cfr This one has an answer the other one doesn't

Comment: @percusse I am aware that you posted an answer at the same time I closed it as a duplicate. That is precisely why I flagged it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For simple and *very* smooth curves you can fake a simple derivative action as in [Derivative of a tikz path?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193285/derivative-of-a-tikz-path/)
However TeX is not the place to do these CAS computations. If you have the closed form curves then you can plug the formulas into `pgfplots` otherwise it will always fail at some point.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{approxderiv}{initial}{%
\state{initial}[width=0.01mm,
                persistent postcomputation={%
                    \def\tempa{0}%
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\plen}{(\pgfdecoratedpathlength-0.01mm)/500}%
                    \def\myderivlist{}%
                },next state=walkthecurve]{}%do nothing
\state{walkthecurve}[width=\plen pt,
               persistent postcomputation={%
                  \pgfmathparse{(sin(\pgfdecoratedangle))}\xdef\tempb{\pgfmathresult}%
                  \pgfmathparse{abs(cos(\pgfdecoratedangle))*\plen}%
                  \expandafter\xdef\expandafter\myderivlist\expandafter{%
                     \myderivlist --++ ({\pgfmathresult pt},{(\tempb-\tempa)*(1cm)})%
                    }%
                  \xdef\tempa{\tempb}%
               }
            ]{}%do nothing
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[style=help lines] (0,-7) grid[step=5mm] (6,2.5);
\draw[decoration=approxderiv,postaction={decorate}] (0,0) ..controls (2,2) and (1,1) .. (3,0);
\draw[red,decoration=approxderiv,postaction={decorate}] (0,-3) \myderivlist;
\draw[blue] (0,-6) \myderivlist;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]